# Will Ubuntu One Feature Revisions?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am considering switching over to Ubuntu One to back up all of my files because of some slight issues I had with Dropbox and I was wondering when Ubuntu One will feature revisions if it will at all.

Answer (score 7):

We have plans to add revisions but not in the next release.

Comment: Until that happens, a good option is [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/).  As an added bonus, all files are client-side encrypted.